# Use php to create a json file structure

Tags: php, json

Any help would be appreciated!

I've been going at this for a little bit now and can't seem to get this to work. What am I doing wrong?

I'm trying to get the output of a JSON structure below using php. Take a look at the differences with the outputs below!

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','1234','root');
$records = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $records[] = $row;
    }
    $json = json_encode($records, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

}

   file_put_contents('records.js', $json, FILE_APPEND);
```

#### What it's outputting now:

```
[

  {
    "id": "2",
    "volume": "volume1",
    "name": "a",
    "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
    "cssanimate": "bounce"
  },
  {

      "id": "2",
      "volume": "volume1",
      "name": "a",
      "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
      "cssanimate": "bounce"
   },
   {

      "id": "2",
      "volume": "volume1",
      "name": "a",
      "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
      "cssanimate": "bounce"
    } 

]
```

#### What I want the output to be:

```
var data = [{

  {
  tags: [{
    "id": "2",
    "volume": "volume1",
    "name": "a",
    "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
    "cssanimate": "bounce"
      }]
  },
  {
    tags: [{
      "id": "2",
      "volume": "volume1",
      "name": "a",
      "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
      "cssanimate": "bounce"
      }]
   },
   {
    tags: [{
      "id": "2",
      "volume": "volume1",
      "name": "a",
      "content": "<img src="image_2.jpg">",
      "cssanimate": "bounce"
      }]
    } 

}]
```

Comment: What is `$data`?

Comment: If you want `tags` key - you should add it by yourself. No one will do it for you.

Comment: @u_mulder sorry! That was an error :)

Comment: @u_mulder haha thanks for the comment but I can't figure it out... that's why I'm here asking the pros. I'm not asking for the answer... maybe some guidance?

Comment: And btw - do you understand difference between `[` and `{` in json? Are you sure you need array of objects of objects? I bet this is invalid structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra level of `{` that's invalid in the desired output, so I'll ignore that. To create an object with the `tags` key, you need to create a PHP associative array using that key. And then to make the tags an array of objects, you need to wrap the row in another array.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
}
```

I'm not sure why you need each object in a single-element array nested inside another object and array, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Thank you! @Barmar I see now how this is done and learned from it. Thanks buddy